# display first page of pdf as image in php

Tags: php, pdf

i would like to display just first page of an uploaded PDF as an image with a link on it to the PDF file. can you guys help me in doing this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This is not possible in pure PHP. What kind of server are you on? Do you e.g. have access to ImageMagick and Ghostscript?

Answer (score 2):

Try this with imagemagick:

```
exec("convert input.pdf[0] output.jpg)";
```

Then in HTML:

```
<a href="input.pdf"><img src="output.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: This will only work if the OP has _ImageMagick_ access on his/her server.

Comment: This will only work if the OP has ImageMagick access on their server *and* GhostScript installed. If that is the case, it's the simplest way so +1

Comment: i don't have ImageMagic on my server. please tell me how do i get that and how do i access that.

Comment: Since Imagemagick uses ghostscript anyway try yourself with gostscript: exec("gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=doc.jpg doc.pdf"); If that doesn't work contact you hosting company and ask them to install Ghostscript and Imagemagick. If they refuse,i am sorry to say that but, you will have to change your hosting company :(